# openxml parsing worddocument problems with hyperlinks

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Hello I'm using the openxml sdk and I like to parse an Word document but there is a Problem with some hyperlinks. They arn't from the hyperlink class.
They are somtimes splitted in runs starting with a run with instrText = HYPERLINK. Why are the links two different types of links and what is the best way to parse the linktype wich is splitted in diffrent runs and start with HYPERLINK?

```html
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    </w:rPr>
...   
     <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> HYPERLINK "</w:instrText>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidRPr="00000D8A">
...
    <w:instrText>http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/protractor-vs-selenium-which-is-easier</w:instrText>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
...
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">" </w:instrText>
   </w:r>
   <w:r>
   ...
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidRPr="00F145BD">
    <w:rPr>
   ...
     </w:rPr>
    <w:t>http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/protractor-vs-selenium-which-is-easier</w:t>
   </w:r>
```

Comment: In Word, Hyperlinks are managed by field codes. So the Word Open XML you show is expected and correct. In addition, Field codes have a "text" part, which follows the same internal editing rules as all `<w:t>` text elements. These can be broken up by just about anything, so you can't rely on or force a document to not break up text runs. You need to take this into account. What do you mean, more exactly, by "parsing" this particular information? What is it you need to extract?

Comment: I'm writing a word to markdown converter. So i need to get the hyperlinks and convert them to markdown.

Comment: OK... I'm not familiar with "markdown converter" so I don't quite follow what's required... Are you basically converting the document content to another type of content (HTML for example)? So all you need is the URL of the Hyperlink and perhaps the display text?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i need.